# Axios.post TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm a novice react developer. I'm working on a react project which has Laravel included in it as its backend. When trying to post some fake data by axios I face the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at isUrlMatching (utils.js:56)
    at utils.js:48
    at find (utils.js:17)
    at Object.findHandler (utils.js:46)
    at handleRequest (handle_request.js:40)
    at index.js:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MockAdapter.<anonymous> (index.js:17)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:40)
```

Below is my Code:

```
 axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'alavi',
        phoneNumber: '+989337821192',
        email: 'sajjadhaidari45@gmail.com',
        password: 'fasfasfr'
    }, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(
        response => console.log(response.data)
    ).catch(
        error => console.log(error)
    )
```

please help me know what's wrong.

Comment: Try to log your URL i think it's undefined.

Comment: Did u check network tab in chrome how is the request ?

Comment: @praga2050 yes but when i click on submit button nothing happens in network section.. whats wrong?

Comment: pls post some more details so that we can help